# how to connect to a oracle 12C database in SYSOPER or SYSDBA in PRELIM_AUTH mode using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

I am trying to start the server from my node.js application using npm's oracledb package. But In order to do that I need to connect to the database in PRELIM_AUTH mode with SYSOPER or SYSDBA privileges.

Below is the sample code:

```
var oracledb = require('oracledb');
var dbConfig = require('./dbconfig.js');

oracledb.getConnection(
  {
    user          : dbConfig.user,
    password      : dbConfig.password,
    connectString : dbConfig.connectString
  },
  async function(err, connection) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      return;
    }
    console.log('Connection was successful!');
    await connection.startup();
    connection.close(
      function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err.message);
          return;
        }
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

There's currently (in node-oracledb 2) no support for PRELIM_AUTH mode.  Please open an enhancement request on [GitHub](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues).